# how to modified the image options for fabric.js background image on the canvas in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js library to set an image background but can not get references

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/honey_im_subtle.png', 
canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
 width: canvas.width,
height: canvas.height,
  // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top'
 });
```

I am using this function but there is not a property for canvas.width 
while I get a canvas.getWidth() but it is not working like this .. as well as this is also not working with my case :(

```
 canvas.setBackgroundImage('images/download.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), 
    {
        backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
        backgroundImageStretch: true 
      // above both option are not valid with my case  
    });
```

Comment: Pass a callback on `setBackgroundImage` method as the second parameter, you will get reference to image object as argument on your callback.

Comment: but in call back this is not working
"
          backgroundImageOpacity: 0.5,
          backgroundImageStretch: true"

Comment: can you post an answer by modifying the code in the below section if you don't mind?

Comment: Those two properties(`backgroundImageOpacity, backgroundImageStretch`) are deprecated since v1.3.9 .

Comment: then what's now ? how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `opacity and scale` of image object instead of `backgroundImageOpacity, backgroundImageStretch`.

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://picsum.photos/200/300', (img) => {
  img.set({
    opacity: 0.5,
    scaleX: canvas.width/img.width,
    scaleY: canvas.height/img.height,
  });
  canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.requestRenderAll.bind(canvas));
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.4.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: yes, it works. Thank you so much. so nice of you :)